# My codes are not working (json, arrays)

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$wiki_img = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Google&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500";

$json2 = file_get_contents($wiki_img);
$data2 = json_decode($json2, TRUE);

foreach ($data2['query']['pages'] as $pages)
{
  print_r($pages['source']);
}
```

My codes are not working.

But I can't find what is error.

I got this error

> "Notice: Undefined index: source in C:\xampp\htdocs\"

Comment: `var_dump($pages)` and see what you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your JSON data which you got is

```
{
    query: {
        pages: {
        1092923: {
            pageid: 1092923,
            ns: 0,
            title: "Google",
            thumbnail: {
                source: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Googleplex-Patio-Aug-2014.JPG/500px-Googleplex-Patio-Aug-2014.JPG",
                width: 500,
                height: 375
                },
                pageimage: "Googleplex-Patio-Aug-2014.JPG"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should be..

```
foreach($data2['query']['pages'] as $value){
    echo $value['thumbnail']['source'];
}
```

Output:

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Googleplex-Patio-Aug-2014.JPG/500px-Googleplex-Patio-Aug-2014.JPG
```